# How to assert that a link to another application in a new browseris is correct?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

The AUT has links along the top navigation bar. During normal use, each link opens a related application in a different browser.

Is it possible to do a simple page title assertion on the new application, then return to the AUT and click the next link?  And so on for each link?

For testing, I don't think it matters whether the link target opens in a new browser, or a new tab, or the same tab. As long as I can jump back and forward between the AUT and the "other" application.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample HTML, this is a bit of a shot in the dark.  But--assuming there's a distinct attribute to hook onto--you can collect the links from the navigation div and iterate over each link.  This is a simple, contrived example (where the links do not spawn new browsers/tabs):

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto("http://www.iana.org/domains")

nav_link_hrefs = b.div(:class, "navigation").links.collect { |link| link.href}

nav_link_hrefs.each do |href|
  next if href == "http://www.iana.org/domains" # skip self-referential link
  b.link(:href => href).click
  b.back
end
```

In terms of doing a "simple page title assertion", I'm not sure how you'd know the page title in advance.  But I'd suggest looking into [MiniTest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest) or [rspec](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/frames) for an assertion library.

Lastly--if window-switching is required for your use case--check out the watir-webdriver [window-switching documentation](http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-popups/).

Comment: Not quite the answer - probably because my question wasn't clear. All this info is very valuable to a newcomer, and I will use all of it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Here's the partial code:

```
@browser.goto URL
current_url = @browser.url
new_window_url = @browser.link(:text, "Other site").href
@browser.goto(new_window_url)
# test the other site
assert(@browser.text.include?("This is the other site"))
@browser.goto(current_url) # back to the first site
# repeat for all the other navigation links
```